# unzip error "End-of-central-directory signature not found"

Tags: unzip

I try to unzip a zip file, but got an error:

```
$ unzip COCR2_100.zip 
Archive:  COCR2_100.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
note:  COCR2_100.zip may be a plain executable, not an archive
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of COCR2_100.zip or
        COCR2_100.zip.zip, and cannot find COCR2_100.zip.ZIP, period.
```

I googled but didn't find a solution. I was wondering why it is and how I should fix it? Thanks!

The zip file can be downloaded from [COCR2_100](http://www.xurion.be/cocr2/COCR2_100.zip). It is an application, and here is its website http://users.belgacom.net/chardic/cocr2.html.

My OS is 10.10.

Comment: I was able to download and extract the program without any problems using the mirror link.  Perhaps your download is corrupt?  here is my md5sum output on the file:    a55352aac3193948478952dea33828ef  /home/chuck/Desktop/COCR2_100.zip

Comment: If you md5sum the file and get the same result "a55352aac3193948478952dea33828ef" Then your download is good, but if it isn't EXACTLY the same, then your download is corrupt

Comment: @Ctuchik: Thanks! The mirror one is good. The original one is broken.

Comment: np bud, glad i could be of service.

Comment: Use the more robust `jar xvf archive.zip`, or try to fix the archive with `zip -F archive.zip -O archive-fixed.zip` (or `-FF`, see `man zip`).

Comment: Future readers: if you encounter this error while trying to unzip a file from GitHub, try downloading the file with `wget`. [More info here](https://askubuntu.com/q/285976/682592).

Comment: Similar question on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16261100/cant-download-github-project-with-curl-command

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The problem is exactly what it says. Unzip can't find the line of code that signals the end of the archive, so either:

1. The archive is corrupt.
2. It is not a .zip archive.
3. There are more than 1 parts to the archive, but that doesn't seem possible to me.
   You should try the other mirror too. It worked for me.

P.S. Notice how the program is made for Windows. So you need Wine (from http://www.winehq.com or the Ubuntu Software Center) to run it.

Comment: It seems that "unzip" is not very robust and therefore cannot cope with corrupted (or incompletely downloaded) archives.

Comment: Not exactly, I can unpack `such file` by Winrar or other popular Windows tools. Example file `stanford-chinese-corenlp-2016-10-31-models.jar` at  http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml .

Answer (score 241):

Try this excellent solution:

```
jar xvf COCR2_100.zip
```

steps:

1. drag and drop file into terminal window.
2. use keyboard arrows to navigate to start of line in terminal
3. type `jar xvf` in front of your file name, remembering to leave space before the start of your file name.
4. grab a beer and watch terminal work its magic as it extracts files.

The location of where the new files go varies, but usually best trick to find them is click on your computer name in Finder which should display most recent activity at top of all files.

If the `jar` command is not available, you can install `fastjar` by pasting the following in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install fastjar
```

Comment: Why do you think it might really be a `jar` file?

Comment: @EliahKagan it is not, but the trick works

Comment: I found that the "fastjar" program works as well. It does not require Sun's openjdk. It can be installed from the Ubuntu package "fastjar".

Comment: in my case the file was over 2G, so either the file system or chrome failed. However, this command did unzip the first 2G worth of data, and I downloaded the rest of what I needed a piece at a time.

Comment: Java's jar uses the zip format internally, and it's not surprising that, one "unzipper" would handle corruption better than another.

Comment: Wow this is exactly what I was looking for! Should def be the accepted answer. Any idea why this works?

Comment: I think this works for corrupt (or incompletely downloaded) files because the `jar` utility does not check for the `End-of-central-directory` signature before starting the extraction. If that really is the case, chances are you might not be able to extract every file and the utility might end with an error like `Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream` at the end.

Comment: Upvoted. Thank you: it was a headache to repair 6.5Gb zip with "zip -FF": produced "fixed" archive was tthe esact copy of damaged (incomplete) original one. I knew that .jar files are zips internally, but I never used the jar executable to unpack zip archives :-)

Comment: if you dont have jar command on ubuntu, try "aptitude install fastjar" or with apt-get as well

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!

Comment: Winning answer. Because it fully answers the question with a more helpful solution.

Comment: Did not work for me, but the answer by Campa with `7z` did the trick.

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked a charm ! FireFox said the download were done, so I have no idea why that  signature should be missing … Annyways, +1 !

Comment: It does not work for me, It has it `Ick! 0x3334449` after I issued the `jar xvf file-name.zip`.

Answer (score 57):

Unzipping with **7z** worked for me:

```
7z x COCR2_100.zip
```

---

Install via APT with `apt install p7zip-full`.

Comment: Thanks @Campa `7z` helped me to open a password encrypted zip with the similar issue.

Comment: @Campa Thanks , I was facing problem to unzip with artifacory , build of elixir app.

Comment: @campa, Thanks. This worked

Comment: This also worked for me, but on a mac I first needed to run: `brew install p7zip`

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar issue today and had some success with dd and gunzip. Try this:

```
dd if=corrupt.zip | gunzip -f > xx.csv
```

In my case I still got the "gunzip: stdin: unexpected end of file" error but at least I got some output to view.

Comment: I found that `zcat corrupt.zip > xx.csv` did almost exactly the same thing....

Comment: Why do you output it as a csv?

Answer (score 8):

**Error can be caused by mixing up archive types:**

I noticed that when using **`unzip`**, but on a **`gunzip`** (GNU) archive I would get this error, e.g.

> End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is
>   not   a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.
>   In the   latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be
>   found on   the last disk(s) of this archive. unzip:  cannot find
>   zipfile directory in one of create_tables.sql.gz or
>           create_tables.sql.gz.zip, and cannot find create_tables.sql.gz.ZIP, period."

Using **`gunzip`** on this same archive performed without errors.  !!

Comment: That did for my script which creates a zip file on the remote machine with gzip. unzip was failing. gunzip is working great now.

Answer (score 1):

I think the guys/gals that responded to you is on the right track it is very well a corrupted file. If that is the case then try another mirror to download the file. Your may try to install rar by opening terminal  `sudo apt-get install rar`  which for a true zip file rar is a little overkill. However it does add support for other formats and  allows you to extracts different file types.