# Download ZIP file with curl command

Tags: downloads, command-line, zip, curl

How can I download ZIP file with curl command? I tried `curl -sO`, but error occurred. I want to download zip file from address:
http://github.com/ziyaddin/xampp/archive/master.zip

but can't. What must I type?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Does anybody else see the irony in downloading a zip file which has the zip command on it. So once you've download it. Then you can use zip command inside the zip file to unzip the zip command you need to unzip the zip. Ok cool ;)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I used `curl -LO` and it worked fine. `wget` works too.

Comment: Worked for me. using Windows 7

Comment: Worked for me on Windows 11 using curl v8.0.1

Comment: Worked also for me in wsl Linux subsytem of Windows 10 using `wget`

Comment: The `L` flag is to follow redirects: `-L, --location           Follow redirects`

Answer (score 35):

Try wget instead of curl: `wget http://github.com/ziyaddin/xampp/archive/master.zip`

Comment: Can the downvoter explain? Or is the other poster?

Comment: Could you explain why `wget` instead of `curl`?

Comment: less command lines (if you care) - which means less options, But the biggest difference is that wget support recursive download

Comment: Don't know why, but I had an error issuing `unzip` on the file downloaded with `curl`, and it worked fine with `wget`

Comment: @Dinei you need to try `curl -OL <URL>` once I added `-L` it fixed it for me.

Answer (score 31):

You can use:

```
curl https://github.com/ziyaddin/xampp/archive/master.zip -O -J -L
```

Saves as: `xampp-cli-master.zip`

- use `-L` in case there is a redirect found.
- use `-O` for remote filenames (`master.zip`)
- use `-J` (use with `-O`) to allow remote header filename (`xampp-cli-master.zip`)

Or use `-o` to create your own filename:

`curl https://github.com/ziyaddin/xampp/archive/master.zip -L -o MyFilename.zip`

Saves as: `MyFilename.zip`

Note: (GitHub supports SSL - use `https://`)

---

You could also use a `curlrc` [config file](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-K) or alias the CURL command to use `curl -O -L` to allow it to work similar to WGET.

Consult: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#OPTIONS (See: [-O](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-O), [-J](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-J), [-L](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-L), [-o](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-o))

Note the warning of using CURL with the -J option:

> There's no attempt to decode %-sequences (yet) in the provided file
>   name, so this option may provide you with rather unexpected file
>   names.
>
> **WARNING**: Exercise judicious use of this option, especially on Windows. A rogue server could send you the name of a DLL or other file
>   that could possibly be loaded automatically by Windows or some third
>   party software.

Comment: Lol, this wins just because you get to do the [J.Lo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jennifer_Lopez) curl: `curl -JLO ...`

Comment: @icc97 LOL. Never occurred to me - that might be easier to remember, too..

Answer (score 7):

If you want to download the file use `wget [option]... [URL]...` instead.

For more information regarding the options, just type this into your Terminal: `man wget`

For you purpose:

`wget http://github.com/ziyaddin/xampp/archive/master.zip`

Note that the .zip file will be saved in the current directory you are in.

Comment: It would be helpful to explain the advantages of using `wget` over of `curl`. For anyone wondering the differences between the two [see here](http://daniel.haxx.se/docs/curl-vs-wget.html).

Comment: @JorgeBucaran I read the comparison written by the author of `curl` who also contributes to `wget` in a minor role. One glaring omission (based on my one time small project) is that wget is 10 times faster than curl (<2 seconds vs. 12 seconds) retrieving sunrise and sunset times from `https://www.timeanddate.com`

Comment: So, sometimes when you use wget and the file is not served directly but instead the url tells a service where to locate and serve the file, what you end up downloading is a html. So curl is better for some files instead

Answer (score 4):

To download files in GitHub (or any other site that make redirects) using `curl`, you must pass `-L` (Follow redirects), so use:

`curl -L http://github.com/ziyaddin/xampp/archive/master.zip -o xampp.zip`

Answer (score 1):

"curl -LOk" makes it using insecure protocols (-k), disabling SSL certificate checks (which fail because of the incorrect path not matching the certificate), and create the output file using the filename (-O) proposed from the remote server (also insecure).
In my opinion, the server should better be configured create local redirecting aliases where needed, to avoid having to pass this non conforming part of the URL. But the redirection is made using an HTTP redirect only (HTTP error 30x), which causes problems to curl that does not follow (by default) this (unsecure) redirection, and option (-k) disables this security check.
So instead of using HTTP redirects (moved permanently), please add some internal link on the filesystem of the server. If this is needed because the URL is in fact hosted on another physical server with no direct access between their filesystems, you should use another DNS name for this host, so that clients will query the correct one directly, without any redirect.
Then fix your web pages (you may use your webserver logs to see where HTTP 30x redirects are returned and which webpages may need to be checked and updated).
Forcing clients to use unsecure/unchecked protocols is not a good option.

So this is definitely a problem of very bad configuration on the web server: try contacting their admin to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

well, you can use **Axel** as well. axel is a light command line download accelerator. it supports `HTTP, HTTPS, FTP` and `FTPS` protocols. its nice and faster alternative.

install `axel` using :

```
apt-get install axel
```

then download your file by:

```
axel http://github.com/ziyaddin/xampp/archive/master.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the option `-L` to follow redirects, you can use also the `--output` option to give a path and a name to the zip file. For example:

```
sudo curl -L https://github.com/CISOfy/lynis/archive/master.zip --output /etc/lynis.zip
```

Note: Use sudo if you don't have permissions to write to the target folder.