# Unzip 5GB zip file

Tags: zip, unzip

I have here 5GB zip file but I have no idea how to unzip that.

I tried:

```
7z x file.zip
```

Returns: `Error: Can not open file as archive`

```
jar xvf file.zip
```

Returns: `jar: error opening file.zip for reading: Value too large for defined data type`

```
unzip file.zip
```

Returns:

```
End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
note:  file.zip may be a plain executable, not an archive
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of file.zip or
        file.zip.zip, and cannot find file.zip.ZIP, period.
```

The file does seem to be a zip archive:

```
$ file file.zip
file.zip: Zip archive data, at least v1.0 to extract
```

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: The correct way to unzip a zip file is : `unzip file.zip` it looks like your zip file may be corrupted. Can you download it again and do a checksum to see if the file is ok?

Comment: _"note:  file.zip may be a plain executable, not an archive"_ - what does `file file.zip` say?

Comment: @LnxSlck: how to do a checksum? I'm Ubuntu newbie, can you please help me? The other things I tried when unzip file.zip didn't work.

Comment: @steeldriver: `file.zip: Zip archive data, at least v1.0 to extract`

Comment: This has been answered before here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/54904/unzip-error-end-of-central-directory-signature-not-found

Comment: @LnxSlck: this topic I've read before, but doesn't solve my problem. Archive isn't corrupt and it is .zip archive. I don't understand point 3, but it's full archove, not only a part.

Comment: @LnxSlck there's no answer there. The OP has already tried all the solutions suggested, they're right there in the question.

Comment: do you know who made it? Because... I would assume there might be a 2nd file (and more) to make up the complete file.

Comment: Maybe this is file belongs to a serie of files for example 1 of 3 files. What file is it? Have you downloaded it from the internet?

Comment: Done, I've just downloaded the zip file once again, and `unzip` works. First time, the file was probably corrupt, now everything is okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file does indeed appear to be a zip archive. I have no idea why you're getting this problem. It sounds like a limitation of `unzip` but that, again, is very unlikely. Anyway, one possible workaround is to use `zcat` instead. However, **this will only work as expected if the compressed data is a single file**, not a bunch of files and directories:

```
zcat file.zip > file.unzipped
```

The other option of course is that the file is either corrupt (you say it's not in your comment but give no evidence to support the claim) or part of a larger archive. Without more information about the file itself we can't help.

Comment: it returns `gzip: file.zip has more than one entry--rest ignored` - in the archive, there are more files, not just one (if I understood well error message).

Comment: @panther yes, that makes sense. It was a long shot. Are you _sure_ this is not just a single piece of a larger archive? Where did you get the file from? What makes you so sure it's not corrupt?

Comment: yes, I'm sure it's complete and not corrupt archive, because on Windows on the other computers in the past we opened similar files regularly (it's a partional backup of e-mail data). This zip file was created with the same bash script on server.

Comment: @panther that does not mean its not corrupted. Can you open this particular archive on Windows? A file can be corrupted when you transfer it between computers for example. Or when something changed while the archive was being created.

Comment: No, I have no chance to try to open this file on another computer :-(

Comment: I tried to download that once again from server and it works. There probably has to be any error during downloading the file first time. Now, `unzip` works fine.

Comment: @panther ah, there you go. Makes sense :)

Comment: I didn´t expect it can download incorrectly, and it was first time I tried to unzip that on Ubuntu. I´ve never have similar problem before, so I didn´t suppose the problem could be here :-).